# How to filter data based on the combination of three columns' values in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two datasets which have the same columns, but have different values in some rows.
Here is the example:

**Table A**

```
ID    Ver    change    Indicator
01     00     01         Delete
01     00     02         Delete
02     01     03         Delete
02     03     02         Delete
03     01     01         Delete
```

**Table B**

```
ID    Ver    change    Indicator
01     00     01         Keep
01     00     01         Keep
02     02     03         Keep
02     03     02         Keep
03     01     02         Keep
```

What I want is to filter the rows in Table A based on the combination of columns `ID`, `Ver`,`change`. if this combination is not in Table B, the corresponding row should remain.

My desired output is this for this example:

**Filtered Table A**

```
ID    Ver    change    Indicator
01     00     02         Delete
02     01     03         Delete
03     01     01         Delete
```

I've tried this, but it returns the same table as Table A:
`Table_A[~Table_A[['ID','Ver','change']].isin(Table_B[['ID','Ver','change']])]`

I've also found some answers realted to `zip()` function use Tuple to solve, but I have no idea how to apply them to this problem.
I appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inner join based on these 3 column:

```
New_Table = pd.merge(Table_A, Table_B[['ID','Ver','change']], how='inner', on=['ID','Ver','change'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the first solution, won't it check each column separately instead of a combination of three columns?

Comment: @Fangyuan yes of course you are right, I am editing the answer

Answer (score 0):

Alright this works:

`tablea.csv`

```
ID,Ver,change,Indicator
01,00,01,Delete
01,00,02,Delete
02,01,03,Delete
02,03,02,Delete
03,01,01,Delete
```

`tableb.csv`

```
ID,Ver,change,Indicator
01,00,01,Keep
01,00,01,Keep
02,02,03,Keep
02,03,02,Keep
03,01,02,Keep
```

And now this code loads / removes the duplicates:

```
In [41]: df_a = pd.read_csv("tablea.csv", dtype={'ID':'str', 'Ver':'str', 'change':'str'})

In [42]: df_b = pd.read_csv("tableb.csv", dtype={'ID':'str', 'Ver':'str', 'change':'str'})

In [43]: df_a.set_index(["ID", "Ver", "change"], inplace=True)

In [44]: df_b.set_index(["ID", "Ver", "change"], inplace=True)

In [45]: df_a[df_a.index != df_b.index].reset_index()
Out[45]:
   ID Ver change Indicator
0  01  00     02    Delete
1  02  01     03    Delete
2  03  01     01    Delete
```

Last expression `df_a[df_a.index != df_b.index].reset_index()` contains the desired result.